# Memory leak on using uimages

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, storyboard, instruments

I am working on a project that contains lot of images. i just wanted to be sure that if any of my view controller that contains about 70 images and i have put those images via storyboard will that too consumes memory of about 2-3 MB ?,as it showing in instruments or it due to some memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your description there is no leak, your code should be able to give more info. So in short if application is loaded and images are rendered, the it takes up memory. However if you are not managing the memory correctly, it will leak and your question does not contain sufficient info to make any comment on that.